# Compute output volume of a layer in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Given this task :

[image]

Am I right if I apply the formula : ((n + 2p - f / s) + 1) to compute the volume of the layer ?

```
Layer CONV 1 : 1242 x 378 x 64
Layer POOL 1 : 621 x 189 x 64
Layer CONV 2 : 310 x 94 x 128
Layer POOL 2 : 78 x 24 x 128
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the formula is correct up to the typo in where the bracket should be: `((n + 2p - f) / s + 1)`